# Datatable Comparison of - primary keys is not working

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, comparison, primary-key

I have written a code block which Compares datatable for Scheme differences.

this is the code:

```
    private static void ValidateSchema(DataTable originalTbl, DataTable otherTbl)
    {           

        var primaryKeyDoesNotMatch = originalTbl.PrimaryKey != otherTbl.PrimaryKey;
        if(primaryKeyDoesNotMatch)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("primary key does not match");
        }

        var primaryKeyDoesNotExist = originalTbl.PrimaryKey == null;
        if(primaryKeyDoesNotExist)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("primary key does not exist");
        }

        var otherTableHasAdditionalColumns = (from x in otherTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>() where !originalTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Any(y => y.ColumnName == x.ColumnName) select x).Any();
        if (otherTableHasAdditionalColumns)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Other table does have additional columns.");
        }

        var columnsAreMissingInOtherTable = (from x in originalTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>() where !otherTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Any(y => y.ColumnName == x.ColumnName) select x).Any();
        if (columnsAreMissingInOtherTable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Other table does not have all the columns.");
        }

        var columnDataTypesDoesNotMatch = (from x in otherTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>() where originalTbl.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Any(y => x.DataType != y.DataType) select x).Any();
        if (columnDataTypesDoesNotMatch)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Column's data type does not match");
        }

    }
```

I also have a Unit test for this which has been implemented to test all these scenarios.

the problem is that even when i test the "columnDataTypeDoesNotMatch" or "columnsAreMissinginOtherTable"  it runs till the first IF statement and tells me "primary key does not match" however they do!

any idea why this happens?

your help is appreciated

tanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The `PrimaryKey` can never equal one another (well, unless it's the same table, or they both have `null` - although it should still have two separate `new DataColumn[0]` arrays), because you're performing a reference comparison, and over an array to boot.

Instead, you have to check for example based on the names of the columns involved (and depending on your requirements, data types as well):

```
bool Compare(DataColumn[] primary, DataColumn[] secondary)
{
  if (primary.Length != secondary.Length) return false;
  var names = new HashSet<string>(secondary.Select(col => col.ColumnName));

  return primary.All(col => names.Contains(col.ColumnName));
}
```

You'll have to expand those as required per your requirements, for example based on whether you care about case sensitivity etc.